# Most recent tag before tip in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tags, versioning

I mark releases with `hg tag <version-number>`.  When I release a bugfix, I don't want to increment the version number, but I want to use the most recent version number during the build process.  If I run `hg tags`, it will show `tip` first, then the version numbers in descending order.  I can get it running `hg tags | head -n2 | tail -n1`.  I wonder if there is a more elegant, pure mercurial way to get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I'm answering my own question.  I found the solution, `hg help templates` shows more options than the documentation on the mercurial site.  So `hg tip --template '{latesttag}\n'` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ParentRevSpecExtension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension
It allows you to say `tip~1`.

EDIT: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question.